# Why does bitbucket pipeline not find tests that run inside local docker container?

Tags: django, bitbucket, django-testing, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a repo that holds two applications, a django one, and a react one.

I'm trying to integrate tests into the pipeline for the django application, currently, the message I'm getting in the pipeline is:

```
python backend/manage.py test
+ python backend/manage.py $SECRET_KEY
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

---------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 $SECRET_KEYS in 0.000s
```

However, running the same command in my local docker container finds 11 tests to run. I'm not sure why they aren't being found in the pipeline

My folder structure is like this

```
backend/
- ...
- app/
-- tests/
- manage.py
frontend/
- ...
bitbucket-pipelines.yml
```

and my pipelines file:

```
image: python:3.8

pipelines:
    default:
        - parallel:
            - step:
                name: Test
                caches:
                    - pip
                script:
                    - pip install -r requirements.txt
                    - python backend/manage.py test
```

Comment: Can you check pathing in your script? is it pointing on repo directories regardless on where the script is? For example, if script looking for the files that under `$HOME`, it can not be possible because bitbucket pipelines are using `/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build` directory for builds.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue I was facing(django application) in bitbucket pipeline and in local it's working fine when we are doing it in bitbucket pipeline it's not working, it's installed all the requirements and related packages the last command was not running, my assumption is sqlite3 is not support in bitbucket pipeline.